# Как передать lambda в генератор в качестве аргумента?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
foo = lambda x: x > 0
lst = [-2, 1, 0, -5, 8]

filtered_lst = [x for x in lst if foo ]
print(filtered_lst)
```

Не работает.
Хотя вот так работает:

```
filtered_lst = list(filter(foo, lst))
print(filtered_lst)
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Вы не передали в функцию параметр. Надо `[x for x in lst if foo(x) ]`

Comment: А мот кто-нибудь объяснить почему в filter можно передавать lambda без аргументов? `filtered_lst = list(filter(foo, lst))`

Comment: добавил в ответ про filter  - там на вход функция, а инструмент уже сам её вызывает

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваша `lambda` осталась без аргумента и приняла значение в условии `<function <lambda> at 0x00000000030705F8>`. По умолчанию она `True`, поэтому ваш список не изменялся (равносильно `[x for x in lst if 1==1]`).

Если добавить вызов `()` и аргумент, то функция отработает:

```
filtered_lst = [x for x in lst if foo(x)]
print filtered_lst
# [1, 8]
```

Кстати достаточно обойтись условием в списке `[x for x in lst if x > 0]`

Также можно заметить что вы используете `lambda` как обычную функцию, сравните, запись получается короче на несколько символов всего лишь:

```
def foo(x): return x > 0
foo = lambda x: x > 0
```

Применение lambda, по моему мнению, оправдано там где можно обойтись без объявления, чаще всего как входной параметр, например:

```
t = [[1,22],[3,4],[10,5,16]]
print sorted(t, key=lambda x: sum(x))
#[[3, 4], [1, 22], [10, 5, 16]]
```

А если не использовать lambda, то получается громоздко, да и функция наверняка более нигде не понадобится, что не сделает код читабельней:

```
def my_sort(x):
    return sum(x)
print sorted(t, key=my_sort)
```

`Filter` - это "обособленный" инструмент, рассмотрим его параметры:

```
help(filter)
# Help on built-in function filter in module __builtin__:
# filter(...)
#    filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
def my_filter(x): return x > 0
print filter(my_filter, [-2, 1, 0, -5, 8]) # не нужно на него еще list() накладывать
# [1, 8]
```

Функция (без вызова) и последовательность.В вашем работающем примере, вы правильно указали имя функции и `filter` сделал "свою" задачу. В простом же выражении списка чтобы функция отработал её нужно вызвать.

Плюс... "обособленные" инструменты (в том числе и `filter`, `map`) поддерживают следующий синтаксис:

```
p = [1, 2, 2.5]
print filter(int, p)
# [1, 2]

t = [1, 2, 3]
print map(str, t)
#['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Смысл lambda был в том что бы передавать с помощью неё различные условия для фильтрации